# Loading image from the same folder as project in Python, Pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am trying to make an adventure game in python, and I need to know how to import image, which is in the same folder as the code with pygame. How to do it? I have tried

```
Character = pygame.image.load('Resources/MainCharFront.png')
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open Resources/MainChar_Front.png
```

I really need it to be in the same folder, because I am often switching devices and my file system is always different.

Answer (score 2):

If you have structured your code as a Python package (which you should), you can use the [pkg_resources](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) module to access resource files like images, etc, that are part of your project.

For example, if I have the following layout:

```
./mypackage/__init__.py
./mypackage/main.py
./mypackage/images/character.jpg
```

I can write in `mypackage/main.py`:

```
import pygame
import pkg_resources


Character = pygame.image.load(
    pkg_resources.resource_filename('mypackage', 'images/character.jpg'))
```

You can see this in action below:

```
>>> import mypackage.main
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> mypackage.main.Character
<Surface(359x359x24 SW)>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say that the image is in the same directory as your code, however the path you are showing implies that you are trying to load it from a sub-directory called `Resources`:

```
Character = pygame.image.load('Resources/MainCharFront.png')
```

So you can likely fix your problem by removing that from the path ans just using :

```
Character = pygame.image.load('MainCharFront.png')
```

However that is not the approach that I would recommend. You are better off to keep the resources in a separate sub-directory like `Resources` to try and keep thing organized. You said that you want to use a flat structure with everything in one folder because you move the game around between different systems with different file systems. I will assume from that that you are having issues with the path separator on these different systems. That is fairly easy to handle though.

@larsks has suggested one way that is a good approach. You do not have to go quite that far though to still be able to keep structure in your resources.

The easy way to deal with different path separators on different file systems is to use `os.path.join()` to link your path components with the file system appropriate separator, like this:

```
Character = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Resources', 'MainCharFront.png'))
```

This will allow you to move between Windows, Linux, etc. without having to flatten your structure. The `os.path.join()` can take multiple path components as arguments, not just 2, so you can have as much hierarchy as you need. Just break up the path string into separate strings where the slashes would be. like this:

```
os.path.join('Resources', 'images', 'MainCharFront.png')
```

You can find the docs for the `os.path.join()` command [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html)

Just to be overly clear, the `os.path.join()` method is not the same as the standard string join() method (which joins strings using the separator you tell it to). The `os.path.join()` method determines the separator for you based on the system it is being run on.